# Android webView; Not displaying image having relative path

Tags: android, webview

While trying to use loadUrl(String url, Map additionalHttpHeaders) method of webView, the response that I receive is not able to display the image. Instead of the image, a question mark substitute is used.

So, I tried to hit the same URL using Java code. The HTML code received during this process showed that the  tag's src attribute was using a relative location.

On passing this same HTML code to webView's loadData() method, I get the same output as mentioned in the first case.

Anyway to fix this issue? (In the additionalHttpHeaders I was passing the authorization header)